# Hyphen that appears only if near end of line

Tags: hyphenation

[image]

[image]

I have a section with the title in the picture. If I don't put the hyphen manually, the word `ultimo` does not get hyphenated and stays on the first line, producing an `Overfull \hbox`. But as you can see, the manually put hyphen goes into the `toc` which is not nice. Is there a way to mark a hyphenation point or to insert a hyphen that will be put in only if the line breaks immediately after it?

PS In case you're wondering, the blue italic text conceals a link. I decided to highlight links that way. Any advice on that is welcome, though not properly on-topic in this question :).

Comment: Use `\-` to hyphenate. For example `ul\-ti\-mo`. (I don't know Italian.)

Comment: Please post a MWE, otherwise we are just going to be guessing.

Comment: Also, are you loading `babel`? `\usepackage[italian]{babel}`

Comment: @Sigur yes I am. Or at least the `.log` file says `(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-italian/italian.ldf
Language: italian 2008/03/14 v1.2t Italian support from the babel system`.

Comment: @MickG, did my 1st comment solve your problem?

Comment: @Sigur yes it seems to. The hyphen is now there in the page but not in the toc.

Comment: @Sigur -- i am pretty sure that even using `babel` won't result in automatic hyphenation because of the apostrophe in the "word".  so the "discretionary hyphen" is indeed the correct answer.  post it, please.

Comment: @Sigur You should turn your first comment into an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton an actual experiment, with italian babel and t1 encoding, gives `\T1/cmr/m/n/10 del-l'ul-ti-mo` from `\showhyphens` ... faintly surprises me, too, but i don't speak italian either.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The apostrophe, when the Italian language is active, receives ``\lccode`'=`'``, so it counts as a letter, as far as hyphenation is concerned.

Comment: @MickG Since, as you see below, hyphenation happens without any manual intervention, there's something in your document that prevents it. Maybe you have `\raggedright` in the titles, which stops hyphenation.

Comment: @egreg I am not doing anything like that explicitly as far as I know. I am using a lot of packages and the `report` class though. Could they be responsible? Among my packages, mathptmx multicolumn multirow fontspec xunicode hyperref thmtools babel and many many more.

Comment: @MickG Without a minimal example showing the behavior it's difficult to say. It may just be a problem due to the line width. If you have long section titles it's indeed a *good* idea to set them ragged right.

Comment: @egreg -- thanks for explanation.  (my knowledge of italian is only slightly better than my knowledge of sanskrit.  very low.)

Comment: @egreg as for the line width, I use `\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, marginparsep=0.7cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, let LaTeX decide where the word should be hyphenated.

To do this, use `\-` to hyphenate.

For example `ul\-ti\-mo`. (I don't know Italian, so I don't know if this is the right way to split the word).

Comment: Yes it is @Sigur :).

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. Don't vote, please: it's just for spurring the OP to produce an example.

This reproduces the title as in the image, and the hyphenation is obtained without manual intervention:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=13.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\thesection}{6.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{3}

\section{Aggiustiamo la dimostrazione del primo pezzo dell'ultimo teorema}

Qualcos'altro per avere testo dopo il titolo.

\end{document}
```

[image]