# Footnotes and broken margins

Tags: margins, footnotes

Suppose that for random reasons I want the footnote mark *before* the text it is related to instead of *after* it. Then the code

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

Hello my name is Gaussler and I have a problem with footnotes before linebreaks. If the word is sufficiently long, the line breaks look just \footnote{Footnote}superhypoerproblematic and I don't know what to do about it, so can you help me solve this problem? It would be really nice, and I would appreciate it and +1 your answer and say thank you very much, you're very nice.

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Wait, that looks horrible. The word goes outside the margin. How to solve this?

(BTW, yes, I have noticed the typo. And I don't care.)

Comment: Related: [Why do hyphenated words cause margin violations (and how can I prevent it)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34721/5764)

Comment: in english, any non-letter that precedes a word that should really be hyphenated suppresses the hyphenation check.  thus a "pre-footnote" means that the word won't even be examined for possible hyphenation.  (this isn't true, in some cases, for other languages, like italian -- see the comments to this question: [Hyphen that appears only if near end of line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219673/579).)

Comment: Happened already. ;-)

Comment: `\footnote{x}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}overlongword`. But what's the meaning of footnote markers attached to the following word?

Comment: It's converted from an XML document where this is the standard. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this...

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

  Hello my name is Gaussler and I have a problem with footnotes before linebreaks. If the word is sufficiently long, the line breaks look just \footnote{Footnote}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}superhypoerproblematic and I don't know what to do about it, so can you help me solve this problem? It would be really nice, and I would appreciate it and +1 your answer and say thank you very much, you're very nice.

\end{document}
```

[image: hyphenation after marker]

**EDIT** Corrected thanks to egreg's comment.

Comment: And I don't risk something like a line break between the footnote and the word?

Comment: @Gaussler Actually, I don't know. You might need to tell LaTeX not to break the line there as well, but I'm not certain of the best way to do this.

Comment: @Gaussler Yes, but adding `\nolinebreak` before `\hspace{0pt}` (better than `\hskip0pt`) fixes the problem. Why not `\hskip`? Well, try `\footnote{x}\hskip0pt minuscule`

Comment: @Gaussler I've corrected/adjusted this in light of egreg's comment. (Of course, `\hskip 0pt minus...` gets read as a single instruction which is not what you want!)

Comment: @egreg It causes problems if the footnote is the first word in the paragraph. Then I get a `There's no line here to end`. I tried reversing the order of `\nolinebreak` and `\hspace{0pt}`, and it complied, but no longer worked as intended.

Comment: And I'm converting from an XML document, so I cannot just omit it.

Comment: @Gaussler I'm not sure to follow: if I have `\footnote{foo}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}bar` at the start of a paragraph, I get no error.

Comment: @Gaussler I just checked after seeing egreg's comment and I can't reproduce the error either - not even if the footnote is the first word of the entire document.

Comment: Well, it probably has something to do with the fact that I'm really using my own homemade footnote environment. Well, egreg's comment solved the problem anyway.

Comment: Or did you try doing it as the very first thing in the entire document?

Comment: @Gaussler Both. I tried it at the start of the first paragraph, with nothing prior, and at the start of the second paragraph. Worked fine. No errors.

Comment: Okay, seems the problem only really concerned my own environment. So there is probably no need to change the answer.

Answer (score 2):

My original `\kern0pt` approach suffered from breaking hyphenation.  So far, the only remedy I have found is to manually supply hyphenatation points to the word following the footnote.  In this case, the `\kern` or `\hskip` is unnecessary.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}


Hello my name is Gaussler and I have a problem with footnotes before linebreaks. If the word is 
sufficiently long, the line breaks look just 
\footnote{Footnote}su\-per\-hy\-po\-er\-prob\-lem\-at\-ic and I don't know what to do about it, 
so can you help me solve this problem? It would be really nice, and I would appreciate it 
and +1 your answer and say thank you very much, you're very nice.

Hello my name is Gaussler and I have a problem with footnotes before linebreaks. If the word is 
sufficiently long, the line breaks look xxxxxxxjust 
\footnote{Footnote}su\-per\-hy\-po\-er\-prob\-lem\-at\-ic and I don't know what to do about it, 
so can you help me solve this problem? It would be really nice, and I would appreciate it 
and +1 your answer and say thank you very much, you're very nice.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, I'm (hopefully temporarily) unaccepting your answer while you think. Don't take it personally, I'm sure you'll get it back. :-)

Comment: @Gaussler My revision is improved, but not ideal.  If I were you, I would hold out for egreg or David to mount up and ride to the rescue.

Comment: I'm sorry, egreg chose to correct the other answer. Nevertheless, I'll +1 everything you've posted as a compensation. :-)

Comment: @Gaussler My answer was not deserving of "acceptance".  No need to compensate for that fact.

Comment: I liked the fact that you tried anyway.